# Powershell get directory name

Tags: powershell

I want a code snippet to put into my profile that will always select the most recent folder.

```
(gci C:\Users\$env:username\Documents\releases | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | sort CreationTime | Select-Object Name)[-1]
```

This is my output.

```
Name
----
20201116_124047
```

I would like the output to be a string that I can place into a variable. I am on Powershell 5.1

20201116_124047

Comment: Change `Select-Object Name` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$myvar=Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents\releases" -Directory | sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1
```

Comment: The most recent folder is not showing.  
This is the folder that is showing. 20201116_124047 Timestamp 1:03 PM   
This is the folder that should be showing 20201116_141006 2:10 PM

Comment: My bad, i have added -Descending to sort. Try now please

Answer (score 0):

The property I think you need is `LastWriteTime`, instead of `CreationTime`.

Also, unless you are using a PowerShell version below 3.0, you can use the `-Directory` switch and do not have to use `Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$env:username\Documents\releases" -Directory |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Last 1
```